# Good distance metric for clustering frequency variables?

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset of customers, with variables refering to ABSOLUTE FREQUENCIES (counts). For example, I have the number of times he makes a purchase in weekend, the number of purchases in laborable days, the number of purchases in the morning, afternoon, evening, night... etc.

I want to create custers using kmeans. Which distance metric would you recommend? Euclidean, Manhatan, Hellinger, Jackkard... some other? And which type of normalization/scale/standarization (mean/std, range...)

Thanks!

Comment: stats dogma, uncritically accepted, would have you take the square root of the counts, standardize to mean 0 and unit variance, and then deploy Euclidean distance. Manhatan would be fine too. Neither Hellinger, which is a distance between probability distributions, nor Jaccard, which is a distance between sets, is appropriate.

Comment: @JohnMadden, why standarize is better than normalize (range scale to 0-1)? This one preserves the data shape and distribution... If, insted of counts, I had frequencies from total (0.7 purcheses on laboral days, 0.3 in weekend), should I have to do any scaling?

Comment: "This one preserves the data shape and distribution" they both preserve shape, as they are simply linear mappings. As to your "why", as I mentioned, it is simply stats dogma: both are acceptable. What does "frequency" mean to you? Is it a number between 0 and 1?